# "Ordering by" in mysql query doesn't work when echoing in php later?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code:

```
while ($shop = mysql_fetch_array($shop_result)) {
    $item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_".$shop['ItemCategory']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$shop['ItemId']."' ORDER BY Level");
    $item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result);


echo("<item>");
        echo("<Element>" . $item['ItemElement'] . "</Element>");
        echo("<ItemLevel>" . $item['Level'] . "</ItemLevel>");
echo("</item>");
```

Here is a typical output:

```
</items>
<item>
<Element>8</Element>
<Level>15</Level>
</item>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>2</Level>
</item>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>24</Level>
</item>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>17</Level>
</item>
<items>
```

But the third highest `Level` is at the top? Why? I ordered by ItemLevel? This is my desired output:

```
</items>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>2</Level>
<item>
<Element>8</Element>
<Level>15</Level>
</item>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>17</Level>
</item>
<item>
<Element>4</Element>
<Level>24</Level>
</item>
<items>
```

I really cant figure it out. When I run the same thing in Sequel Pro I get what I want, but it's GUI.

Comment: check the value for that specific entry, maybe you have a space or a hidden character or something that is causing the row to be ordered first. check the order shown when they query is done directly in mysql.

Comment: It's definitely because items come form different loops of `while`

Comment: You're only fetching one row from `$item_result`. The loop is only for `$shop_result`, so the ordering is based on that query.

Answer (score 1):

`Level` would appear to be a string.  So, it is ordering as a string not a number.

Here are two fixes  First, order as a number:

```
order by Level + 0
```

Second, order by length first:

```
order by length(Level), Level
```

Comment: i thought of that too but out of the example then the order should have been 15, 17, 2, 24 but supposedly the LEVEL 15 is the one shown first and 17 at the end.

Comment: Another option would be to do: `ORDER BY Level * 1`

Comment: `ORDER BY CAST(level AS DECIMAL)`

Comment: Level is INT in my database. Could it still be a string for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

You're not fetching all the rows from `$item_result`, you're just fetching the first row. You need another `while` loop.

```
while ($shop = mysql_fetch_array($shop_result)) {
    $item_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_".$shop['ItemCategory']."s WHERE ItemId = '".$shop['ItemId']."' ORDER BY Level");
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($item_result)) {    
        echo("<item>");
                echo("<Element>" . $item['ItemElement'] . "</Element>");
                echo("<ItemLevel>" . $item['Level'] . "</ItemLevel>");
        echo("</item>");
    }
}
```